# Is neo4j compatible with websockets out-of-the-box?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to improve neo4j reading capabilities by not going through the REST API. It [looks like](http://maxdemarzi.com/2014/03/10/its-over-9000-neo4j-on-websockets/) I could improve performances by using websockets. It looks like this article is working on improving performance in embeded databases.

Is a similar endpoint available in the server version (can't find anything on it) ?
I may not have access to the neo4j server per say --> why I need it out of the box or as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiments with using websockets & cypher which was pretty straightforward: https://github.com/jexp/cypher_websocket_endpoint

And for instance http://structr.org supports Websockets on top of Neo4j out of the box.

Comment: I am not using an embedded database. Can I suppose I could do something similar with an extension ?